# translation and rotation of a parabola

Tags: transformation, conic-sections, rotations

I am trying to translate a parabola to the origin, rotate by T radians and then translate back to the original position. I can calculate the new X and Y vectors using matrix operations and the regress to find the coefficients, but instead I'm trying to calculate the coeffecients of the new parabola.

This is what I've tried, but final values are wrong, so there's a mistake somewhere. Please would someone tell me if finding the new coeffs is possible (and my substitution is wrong) or if there is a better method?

```
Y=AX^2+BX+C vertex at (h,k)
Y'=A(X-h)^2+B(X-h)+C-k  translate vertex to (0,0)
X'=X-h  
Y''=Y'cosT+X'sinT   Y''=cosT*(A(X-h)^2+B(X-h)+C-k)+sinT*(X-h)
X''=Y'sinT-X'cosT   

Y'''=Y''+k  final translated, rotated, translated parabola (i think this is wrong)
Y'''=cosT(A(X-h)^2+B(X-h)+C-k)+sinT(X-h)+k  substitute Y'' to plot with original X values
X'''=X+h    

Y'''=A'X^2+B'X+C'   simplify eqn to find new coeffs
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the equation of the rotated parabola in the original coordinate system? If so, unless the angle of rotation is $0$ or $\pi$, it can’t be expressed in the form $y=f(x)$.

Comment: yes I'd like to plot the original parabola and the new rotated parabola both on the original coordinate system to easily compare them

Comment: You’ll have to try a somewhat different approach, then. You can get an equation that’s quadratic in $x$ and $y$ for the rotated parabola, but in general you won’t be able to get $y$ as a function of $x$ since for all but one value of $x$ that satisfies the resulting equation, there will be two corresponding values of $y$. Think about what the parabola looks like after a 90-degree rotation, for instance.

Comment: ok thanks I see what you mean. Would it be correct to calculate 1)the new translated, rotated, translated vectors x' and y', then 2) use multiple regression to find the eqn coeffs 3)plot the old and new parabolas on the same coordinates? The parabola will only be rotated about +-10 degrees maximum.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rotate the original parabola by any angle other than a multiple of $\pi$, the resulting curve cannot be expressed in the form $y=f(x)$. If you start with the equation $$ax^2+bx+c-y=0\tag{1}$$ instead, though, and apply the transformations to that, you’ll end up with a quadratic in $x$ and $y$ that you can then solve for $y$ using your favorite method (complete the square, quadratic formula, &c). It should be a pretty straightforward matter to plot the new parabola from there.

In particular, you’re looking to rotate the parabola through some angle $\theta$ about its vertex $(h,k)=\left(-{b\over2a},c-{b^2\over4a}\right)$. This transformation can be achieved by making the following substitutions in equation $(1)$: $$\begin{align}
x&\to(x-h)\cos\theta-(y-k)\sin\theta+h \\ 
y&\to(x-h)\sin\theta+(y-k)\cos\theta+k.
\end{align} \tag{2}$$ These are just the end result of applying the three transformations that you’ve listed. After rearranging and collecting terms, you end up with an equation of the form $$(\alpha x+\beta y)^2+\gamma x+\delta y+\epsilon=0$$ which you can then solve for $y$ via the quadratic formula: $$y = -{\alpha\over\beta}x\pm\frac12\sqrt{4(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma)x-4\beta\epsilon+{\delta^2\over\beta}}\tag{3}$$

Depending on how you’re plotting these curves, however, a simpler approach might be to generate points on the original parabola and then transform them individually. That is, if you have some parametrization $(x(t),y(t))$ of the parabola, the right-hand sides of $(2)$ give you a parametrization of the rotated parabola.

Another approach is to use the polar form of the equation of a parabola with axis of symmetry parallel to the $y$-axis: $$r={2p\over1-\sin\theta}.\tag{4}$$ This parabola has its focus at the origin, with $p$ the focal distance. You can use this to parametrize the original parabola as $$\begin{align}
x=h+r\cos t&=h+2p{\cos t\over1-\sin t}\\
y=k+p+r\sin t&=k+p+2p{\sin \over1-\sin t}.
\end{align} \tag{5}$$ Note that since the polar equation places the focus at the origin, we have to add $p$ to the $y$-coordinate. The rotated parabola is a straightforward modification to $(5)$. Changing the orientation is just a matter of adding to the angle $t$, but we also have to adjust for the rotation of the focus. For a counterclockwise rotation of $\alpha$, this ends up as $$\begin{align}
x&=h-p\sin\alpha+2p{\cos\left(t+\frac\alpha2\right)\over1-\sin\left(t-\frac\alpha2\right)}\\
y&=k+p\cos\alpha+2p{\sin\left(t+\frac\alpha2\right)\over1-\sin\left(t-\frac\alpha2\right)}.\end{align} \tag{6}$$ Finally, to relate this back to the original equation, we have $p={1\over4a}$, $h=-{b\over2a}$ and $k=c-{b^2\over4a}$.

Comment: thanks amd, I like  your answer and appreciate the help

Answer (score 4):

first of all "Sorry for my english" .......I do a problem in my blog about a rotation of a parabola,wich is rotate about the focus and the equation of the guideline is $ax+by+c=0$ $$$$
firts cleared $y$.
$$y=\frac{-a}{b}x-c$$
we calculated the slope of the perpendicular straight line.
$$m_{2}=-\frac{1}{m_{1}}=\frac{-1}{-a/b}=\frac{b}{a}$$
we have
$$y=\frac{b}{a}x$$
we want the interception points.
$$\frac{b}{a}x=\frac{-a}{b}x-c$$
$$x=\frac{-abc}{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$
now found $y$:
$$y=\frac{b}{a}\frac{-abc}{a^{2}+b^{2}}=\frac{-b^{2}c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$
write this result like a vector:
$$\vec{S}=\left\langle\frac{-abc}{a^{2}+b^{2}}, \frac{-b^{2}c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\right\rangle=\frac{bc}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle-a,-b\rangle$$
the guideline vector is:
$$\vec{V}=\left\langle x,-\frac{a}{b}x\right\rangle$$
norm of $\vec{V}$ is:
$$\|\vec{V}\|=x\sqrt{1+(a/b)^2}=\frac{x}{b}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$
then, the unitary vector $\hat{V}$ is:
$$\hat{V}=\frac{1}{\frac{x}{b}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\left\langle x,-\frac{a}{b}x\right\rangle=\frac{1}{
\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\left\langle b,-a\right\rangle$$
now we calculated the proyection in the guideline: 
$$\hat{V}\cdot\hat{X}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\left\langle b,-a\right\rangle\cdot\langle x,y\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\left(bx-ay\right)$$
now we multiply the result above to the unitary vector guideline:
$$\vec{V}_{proy}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\left(bx-ay\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\left\langle b,-a\right\rangle  =\frac{(bx-ay)}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle b,-a\rangle$$
calculate now $\vec{R}$ wich is the sum of $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{V}_{proy}$
$$\vec{R}=\frac{bc}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle-a,-b\rangle + \frac{(bx-ay)}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle b,-a\rangle$$
finally we calculate the distance between $\vec{R}$ and $\vec{X}$:
$$\vec{D}=\frac{bc}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle-a,-b\rangle + \frac{(bx-ay)}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle b,-a\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle$$
$$\vec{D}=\frac{1}{a^{2}+b^{2}}[ \langle-abc,-b^{2}c\rangle+\langle b^{2}x-aby,a^{2}y-abx\rangle-\langle a^{2}x+b^{2}x,a^{2}y+b^{2}y\rangle]$$
$$\vec{D}=\frac{1}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle-abc-a^{2}x-aby,-b^{2}c-b^{2}y-abx\rangle$$
$$\vec{D}=\frac{1}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle a(-bc-ax-by),b(-bc-by-ax)\rangle$$
$$\vec{D}=\frac{-(bc+ax+by)}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\langle a,b\rangle$$
we now the eccentricity of parabola is $1$, then we have:
$$\sqrt{\vec{X}\cdot\vec{X}}=\sqrt{\vec{D}\cdot\vec{D}}$$
$$\vec{X}\cdot\vec{X}=\vec{D}\cdot\vec{D}$$
this is the same to:
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{(bc+ax+by)^{2}}{(a^{2}+b^{2})^{2}}(a^{2}+b^{2})$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{1}{a^{2}+b^{2}}(bc+ax+by)^{2}$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{1}{a^{2}+b^{2}}((bc)^{2}+2bc(ax+by)+(ax+by)^{2})$$
$$(a^{2}+b^{2})x^{2}+(a^{2}+b^{2})y^{2}=(bc)^{2}+2bcax+2b^{2}cy+a^{2}x^{2}+2abxy+b^{2}y^{2}$$
finally te equation of parabola is:
$$b^{2}x^{2}-2abxy+a^{2}y^{2}-2bcax-2b^{2}cy=(bc)^{2}$$
if the parabola has a translation to the point $(h,k)$, then the equation is:
$$b^{2}(x-h)^{2}-2ab(x-h)(y-k)+a^{2}(y-k)^{2}-2bca(x-h)-2b^{2}c(y-k)=(bc)^{2}$$
God bless you.

Comment: thanks Julio, I appreciate your help and have learnt a lot from your post. I'm sorry I cannot upvote your solution because my own rating is below 15

Comment: @Zeus don't worry, i appreciate your words, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw rotated parabola using pair of functions
$$y_1=\frac{1}{4} \csc ^2(a) \left(2 \cos (a)-2 x \sin (2 a)- \sqrt{2+2 \cos (2 a)-16 x \sin (a)}\right)$$
and
$$y_2=\frac{1}{4} \csc ^2(a) \left(2 \cos (a)-2 x \sin (2 a)+ \sqrt{2+2 \cos (2 a)-16 x \sin (a)}\right)$$
connected at point
$$\left(\frac{1}{4} \cos (a) \cot (a),\frac{1}{4} (\cos (a)+\cot (a) \csc (a))\right)$$
where $a$ - angle of rotation. [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsdRP.png).