# How to resolve problems with rotating the parabola?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, rotations

I looked at this topic on rotating the parabola and noticed there's a bit of a problem

[translation and rotation of a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850872/translation-and-rotation-of-a-parabola)

Suppose for the explicit answer as stated by the user who's answer was voted, the rotation is in fact $$y = -{\alpha\over\beta}x\pm\frac12\sqrt{4(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma)x-4\beta\epsilon+{\delta^2\over\beta}}\tag{3}$$

such that $ \alpha$ represents $cos( \theta)$ and $ \beta$ represents $ \sin(\theta)$.

Well, if you plug in or take the limit to an angle such as $ \pi$ or $ \frac{ 3 \pi}{2}$, then one can see the right side of the equation can't simplify to any $-x^{2}$ terms as one would expect it to from a 180 degree rotation of the parabola. How is this either explained or resolved?

Despite rotation being a continuous transformation, somehow any infinitesimal rotation of $ax^{2}+bx+c$ past 0 degrees seemingly magically gets rid of the $x^2$ term and imposes this radical term, while rotating to those specific angles of $2 \pi n$ or $ \pi n$ somehow spontaneously restores them. It would seem the implicit form retains more information about the curve and allows the $x^2$ term to remain, but it is still not clear exactly what is lost by taking the explicit form prior to applying the rotation.

Comment: Please note that the folks here answer questions as a *favor* to askers, not as an *obligation* to them, and adjust your attitude accordingly.

Comment: You'll note that equation (3) comes from solving the equation $$(\alpha x + \beta y )^2 + \gamma x + \delta y + \epsilon = 0$$ for $y$ via the Quadratic Formula. Unfortunately, the referenced answer omits the caveat that this only works when the equation is actually *quadratic* in $y$ ... which isn't true when $\beta = 0$ (that is, when $\theta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$). In that case, one solves for $y$ directly and gets an $x^2$ term, as expected.

Comment: I was addressing this part of your question: *"[I]f you plug in [...] an angle such as $\pi$ [...], then one can see the right side of the equation can't simplify to any $-x^2$ terms as one would expect it to from a $180$ degree rotation of the parabola. How is this either explained or resolved?"* To recap my comment: *In the case of a $180^\circ$ rotation, the right side of that equation is invalid, since the quadratic formula (from which it derives) simply doesn't apply.* Perhaps this observation is of no value to you, but hey ... I tried.

Comment: *The rotation is in fact $y=g(x)$* - **NO**. A rotation is an isometry, $y=g(x)$ denotes something else.

Comment: A conic section in the plane is the locus of points $(x,y)$ such that $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ for some constants $A,B,C,D,E,F$. Such form is preserved by rotations, but of course the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is not, since nothing grants that by rotating a graph we still have a graph.

Comment: Well the perplexing issue with this is that you can take the limit to those angles, and somehow it doesn't simplify as you arbitrarily approach a 90 degree angle. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "since nothing grants..." because from what I understand it is valid to change coordinate systems within a graph and still end up with a graph, so how would it not be a graph? Why doesn't the limiting case approach ax^2+bx+c? Also, what is that "something else" you mysteriously alluded to? Rotation merely being an isometry doesn't explain anything, because translation is too.